# read-line in let won't read the next line

Tags: scheme, guile

```
  1 (use-modules (ice-9 rdelim))
  2 
  3 (define (show l) (display l))
  4 
  5 (define (read-two-lines)
  6         (let ((count  (read-line))
  7               (l      (read-line)))
  8              (show l))) ; or (show count)
  9              
 10 (read-two-lines)
```

The code above fails to read the second line into l. Instead it just reads the same value twice :-

```
scheme@(guile-user)> (load "test.scm")

line1
line2
line1
```

When line1 followed by line2 is given as input it shows line1 as output instead of line2 . What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Guile installed so I cannot test this, but in Scheme `let` does not guarantee any order of evaluation. So my best guess is that `count` contains the second line, and `l` the first.

Try using `let*` instead of `let`:

```
(define (read-two-lines)
  (let* ((count  (read-line))
         (l      (read-line)))
    (show l)))
```

For a more thorough explanation see [here](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/binding.html#./binding%3ah4).

Comment: Yes let* worked. However both (show count) and (show l) show the first line only.